# Access second child of XML containing namespace using AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, namespaces

I have an XML looks something like this:

```
<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
<Item>
      <SmallImage>
        <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51PF6C7Bq3L._SL75_.jpg</URL>
      </SmallImage>
</Item>
```

Since this XML contains namespaces my AS3 code is set up this way:

```
//  after loading data 

    XML.ignoreProcessingInstructions = false;
    var raw2:XML = new XML( loa2.data );

    var nameSpace:Namespace = new Namespace("http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01");

    trace(raw2.nameSpace::Item.length());

    //  returns 1
```

I am lost as to how to trace the value of the child parameters such as URL

something like

```
    trace(raw2.nameSpace::Item.SmallImage.URL);
```

This doesn't work, any suggestion would answer my next 100 questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I'm not sure it can be done.

So I edited out the namespace:

```
var strr:String = loa2.data.replace( /xmlns="(.+?)"/, "" );
raw2 = new XML( strr );
```

Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it like this:

1. create a namespace file and name it `amazonWebServices.as`:

   ```
   package {
       public namespace amazonWebServices = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01"
   }
   ```
2. in the class where you parse your xml, use that namespace:

   ```
   use namespace amazonWebServices;
   trace(raw2.Item.length());
   ```

Now all items you want to retrieve from the xml object, default to that Amazon `namespace` so you don't have to explicitly use it in every statement.